# ByteArray can be shown as image in swift using UIImage, but not in Kotlin using BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray

Tags: arrays, swift, kotlin, jpeg

I am reading some byte array object from NFC adaptor using Swift and Kotlin,
then I encounterd one problem.

Following protocol I got byte array with length 1983, which is stored in [UInt8], which can be shown in SwiftUI by just passing

```
let uiImage = UIImage(data: data)
```

however, in Kotlin (Android App) I have problem showing this same data as

```
var bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.size, BitmapFactory.Options())
```

now this bitmap is null and just showing

```
--- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
java.lang.NullPointerException: bitmap must not be null
```

I am bit confused what is the cause of this..

If anyone has any idea or suggestion, I would appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: do you check the data object for null before calling BitmapFactory? share your kotlin code

Comment: thanks for the comment, 
I have been wondering what is wrong, then I just figured it out.

I was dealing with JPEG2000 encoded byte string, so I needed to use
https://github.com/ThalesGroup/JP2ForAndroid/tree/master
this library for decoding. cheers